# Page Redirection in SPFX React App

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

What is the easiest way to redirect to another page in an SPFX React app?

My App is fairly simple with only 2 pages each with a web part. I want to redirect from the home page to another page with a parameter that is used by the receiving page as a filter in a REST request.

I am trying to do it using location.href and putting the parameter in the query string, but I get an error 'The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled'

The service worker file 'spserviceworker.js' is coming from a cdn so I don't think it is possible to make changes to it to deal with the issue. I've tried adding another service worker file to the app without success.

I suppose I could look into using the React Router but it seems like a lot of trouble to go to for somthing that should be fairly simple.

Comment: Are you trying to open link in a new tab/window or within same tab?

Comment: using the same tab

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using simple HTML `a` tag hyperlink with `target="_self"`?

Comment: I'm doing the redirect on a button click. I need to get a value to add to the query string before doing the redirect

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the functionality in the 2 web parts into one web part so I don't need to navigate to another page, I just hide and show elements on the page as required. It seems SPFX is not keen on passing a parameter in a query string to another page to be consumed in  web part.